# Optimizing GameObject unique ID assigner Unity

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, optimization

Recently I was working on the door system for my multiplayer game, and I had a problem with door ID (that specifies which door to interact with). I wanted to avoid assigning IDs manually, due to my game has a lot of doors, so I have found a solution - instead of unreliable FindObjectsOfType, I have build following scene looper:

```cs
void IterateThroughScene(Scene scene)
        {
            SortedList<string, NetworkedObject> sortedObjects = new SortedList<string, NetworkedObject>();
            //List<CrossSceneAudioSyncListener> audioListeners = new List<CrossSceneAudioSyncListener>();
            
            foreach (GameObject sceneRootObject in scene.GetRootGameObjects())
            {
                foreach (NetworkedObject netObj in sceneRootObject.GetComponentsInChildren<NetworkedObject>())
                {
                    Vector3 position = netObj.transform.position;
                    string transformHash = position.x.ToString("0.00") + position.y.ToString("0.00") + position.z.ToString("0.00");
                    transformHash = Hashing.MD5(transformHash);
                    
                    sortedObjects.Add(transformHash, netObj);

                    //CrossSceneAudioSyncListener audioListener = netObj.GetComponent<CrossSceneAudioSyncListener>();
                    //if(audioListener != null) audioListeners.Add(audioListener);
                }
            }

            //CrossSceneAudioSyncInstance.LoadObjects(audioListeners);
            
            Dictionary<ushort, NetworkedObject> preparedObjects = new Dictionary<ushort, NetworkedObject>();
            ushort lastId = _ids[scene.name];
            
            foreach (var part in sortedObjects)
            {
                NetworkedObject preparedObject = part.Value;
                preparedObject.GetObjectData().id = lastId;
                preparedObjects[lastId] = preparedObject;
                lastId++;
            }

            _ids[scene.name] = lastId;
            _registeredObjects[scene.name] = preparedObjects;
        }
```

Here I list step-by-step what this method is doing:

- SortedList is instantiated to hold objects
- 2 foreach's are getting all objects in the scene

  - here script generates MD5 of position and adds it to SortedList
- After that, Dictionary instance is created to hold final data
- Next foreach is done, to loop through SortedList and assign NetworkedObject IDs in a reliable way.

This was doing a great job in small/medium scenes, but I started having serious problems with big scenes - I have a good PC & itaration takes **12 seconds**, and my game's target are medium PCs.

So, Do you have any idea how can I optimize this algorithm?

Comment: Can you not just tag all of the doors and use [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html). I do not know how the internal `FindObjectsOfType` works, so I can not compare the effectiveness of this code. The only place I can imagine making the search more efficient is pruning. You are looping through every object in your scene then getting every child object that has a component. You can make doors mark all root parents as having a door for easier lookup.

Comment: FindObjectOfType isn't a reliable way to do it. It may return objects in a different order, which is unacceptable, and sometimes I don't have a choice & need to use child objects

Comment: Or instead of looking through a haystack for a needle, just tell make the needle tell you about itself. You can have the doors grab the reference of your door manager to then have it assign ids as a function is called, or implement the [Singleton Pattern](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) with a static instance.

Comment: What is the exact use case of setting these ids every time in-game? Why not make an editor script that does this? Have it assign ids then store the reference in your manager in order.

Comment: Editor script does not save values. I tried it.

Comment: What do you mean it does not save values? You were most likely not [marking the scene as dirty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty.html). If you really need to do this at runtime, make an async loading screen and just toss it up while this happens if you need it to happen. I would advise scrapping it and making an editor tool work tho.

Comment: @TEEBQNE Thanks for MarkSceneDirty! Now editor script works as intended! This algorithm is now useless.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that helped. I'll type up some form of a condensed answer going over my points in the comments so the question can be closed.

Comment: Actually `GetComponentsInChildren` is reliable to always return the same order (basically the same order they have top to bottom in your hierarchy) .. so the hash and sort thing is pretty unnecessary

Comment: Note also that if you implement the editor script the right way it will handle the dirty marking itself automatically ... But that's hard to tell without seeing your editor script of course ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I do not know the internals of `FindObjectsOfType` it is hard to compare the method to your snippet. You did however mention that order matters, and as `FindObjectsOfType` is not guaranteed to return objects in any particular order, it would not work for your use case.

To optimize the snippet you would need to prune your search in some way. As you are looking at all root gameObjects, you can mark each root object with the number of doors that it has as children, and keep a counter for each root. That way, once you reach the number needed sent from the children, it can stop searching that root object.

However, as it seems you would just like to assign ordered ids to objects in a scene for referencing, I would advise to use an editor tool to handle the assignment. The code would be near identical but with the advantage of not needing to care about overhead during runtime as it is computed outside of the game. When implementing any editor tool that alters your scene, make sure to [mark the scene as dirty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty.html) to assure Unity will save the changes.